# Displaying MySQL data with php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display all records from my table `CarCollection` using the following code. Right now I am only able to return the 1st record. how can I achieve this?

```
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","USER_NAME","PASSWORD");
if (!$connection)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("DATABASE_NAME", $connection);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM CarCollection");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

mysql_close($connection);
```

Comment: You need to use a while loop. while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<?php

$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","USER_NAME","PASSWORD");
if (!$connection)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("DATABASE_NAME", $connection);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM CarCollection");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

echo $row[0];
echo $row[1];
}


mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Above is correct - I normally have another part to the while loop to make sure that the result is still set:

```
<?php

$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","USER_NAME","PASSWORD");
if (!$connection)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("DATABASE_NAME", $connection);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM CarCollection");
while($result && $row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

echo $row[0];
echo $row[1];

//Or You can Name the Columns
echo $row['name'];


}


mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Close the mysql connection after **mysql_query** is good programming practice.

Comment: isn't this correct? its the last line of code. `mysql_close($connection);`

Answer (score 0):

Add a while loop to the mysql_fetch_array(); thats it...