# Display data from mysql table using jquery & PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a database that has around 250 item category that a user can browse through by clicking on a drop down menu and so on...

My problem is how to work out what item has been clicked by the user so that they can be directed to that page e.g Polo in below case (I have provided coloumn  name = Polo) to fetch the data in relation to Polo but wont be practical assign each & every element.

Is there a way I can assign a variable to name attribute, which will automatically fetch the item clicked by the user?

```
<a href="#">General Equipmemt</a>
                <div class="cbp-hrsub">
                    <div class="cbp-hrsub-inner"> 
                        <div>
                            <h4>Sports</h4>
                                  <ul>
                                    <li><a href="Polo.php" >Polo</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Soccer</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Cricket</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Hockey</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Baseball</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Rowing</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Rugby</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Tennis</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                       </div>
                    </div>
```

---

Here is how I am tracking the information from the DB

```
     <?php
         $q = "SELECT subgroup FROM jqm_categories WHERE name = 'Polo' ";
         $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

         While($list = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) {?>

     <a href="#" class="catag"><?php echo $list['subgroup'].'<br/>';?></a>

            <?php } ?>
```

Comment: `name` is a [MySQL Keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/keywords.html) so you may want to use more caution when naming your columns. What you're asking is fairly easy to do and could be considered PHP101, MySQL101 and [jQuery101](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Displaying MySQL data with php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799973/displaying-mysql-data-with-php)

Comment: Thanks @JayBlanchard this question is about the PHP side which I am okay to work out. I think I need some form of event handler that can get hold of the clicked data and fetch the information relevant to it using PHP

Comment: Did you want someone to write the jQuery for you? Or did you want to try to write it and come back to us with the problems?

Comment: I m more than happy to do that of myself but are you able guide me how it can be done as I very little of jquery. Perhaps if something to read that will guide me in the right direction

Comment: Read the jQuery 101 link above and don't be afraid, you cannot break anything permanently :)